# Read 5GB Json file with similar json objects in each row and split them to multiple json files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a json file with multiple json objects. We need to split the file to multiple json files with proper format and configurable chunk size.

I have tried the below code and it is taking longer time to fetch the number of records in the file.

The overall time taken for each file is around 18 minutes. Need to reduce the time. Below is the sample data

Input:

```
{"job": "developer"}
{"job": "taxi driver"}
{"job": "police"}
```

Output

```
{
  "ROOT": [
    {
      "job": "developer"
    },
    {
      "job": "taxi driver"
    },
    {
      "job": "police"
    }
```

Code I tried and is taking longer to fetch the length of the record

```
import os
import json
import glob
import time
import shutil
start = time.time()


def filesplit(fInputname,farchivedir,foutdir):
    File_Extension = '.json'
 
    # using partition()
    # String till Substring
    x=foutdir.find(File_Extension)
    res=foutdir[0:x]
    with open(fInputname, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f1:
        ll = [json.loads(line.strip())  for line in f1.readlines()]

        #Total number of records in the input json file
        print(len(ll))

        #50000 means we getting splits of 50000 json objects
        size_of_the_split=50000
        total = len(ll) // size_of_the_split

        #Number of files getting generated
        print(total+1)
    for i in range(total+1):
        jsonData=ll[i * size_of_the_split:(i + 1) * size_of_the_split]
        json.dump( {'ROOT': jsonData}, open(res + "_" + str(i+1) + ".json", 'w',encoding='utf8'), ensure_ascii=False, indent=True)
    shutil.move(fInputname,farchivedir)
     

for name in glob.glob("C:\\Users\\JSON\\Input\\*.json"):
    print(name)
    filesplit(name, name.replace('C:\\Users\\JSON\\Input','C:\\Users\\JSON\\OriginalFiles_BKP'),name.replace('C:\\Users\\JSON\\Input','C:\\Users\\JSON\\Output'))
  

end = time.time()
print('completed')
print("The time of execution of above program is :",
      (end-start) * 10**3, "ms")
```

Comment: If your input format is exactly like that you could try a more simple approach: Write `{"ROOT": [\n`; write as many lines as you like, just add a comma except for the last one; write a `]}`.

Comment: Can you please provide me the code? @KlausD.

Comment: Have you tried json.load(f1) f1.readlines() creates a list (5gb file in memory), loading file directly will save this step. Can you check how long does it take?

Comment: From your description it seems that the file is not JSON in its entirety but contains one JSON structure per line. Therefore, read one line at a time, use json.loads() to parse it then add the resulting dictionary to your ROOT list

Answer (score 0):

I think I would try bypassing the json package and loading all the rows into memory and just try and crafting the result files by hand.

Maybe something like this:

```py
MAX_ROWS_PER_FILE = 2
NEW_LINE = "\n"
OPENER = f"{{{NEW_LINE}  \"ROOT\": ["
CLOSER = f"{NEW_LINE}  ]{NEW_LINE}}}"
file_out = None
with open("file_test.json_records", encoding="utf-8", newline="") as filein:
    for index, row in enumerate(filein):
        if index % MAX_ROWS_PER_FILE == 0:
            is_first_row = True
            if file_out:
                file_out.write(CLOSER)
                file_out.close()
            file_out = open(f"file_test_{index // MAX_ROWS_PER_FILE}.json", "w", encoding="utf-8", newline="")
            file_out.write(OPENER)
        if is_first_row:
            file_out.write(f"{NEW_LINE}     {row.strip()}")
            is_first_row = False
        else:
            file_out.write(f"{NEW_LINE}    ,{row.strip()}")
    file_out.write(CLOSER)
    file_out.close()
```

I think given **file_test.json_records** of:

```
{"job": "developer"}
{"job": "taxi driver"}
{"job": "police"}
```

That should give you two files:

**file_test_0.json**

```
{
  "ROOT": [
     {"job": "developer"}
    ,{"job": "taxi driver"}
  ]
}
```

and

**file_test_1.json**

```
{
  "ROOT": [
     {"job": "police"}
  ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Stop reading all the data into memory at the same time. Process the file in chunks, you can use `itertools.islice` on the file iterator:

```py
import itertools
import json
import pathlib


def file_split(
    json_lines: pathlib.Path, output_dir: pathlib.Path, chunksize: int = 50000
) -> None:
    """
    Splits a newline-delimited JSON file into smaller chunks and saves them in the specified output directory.
    Creates a subdirectory with the same name as the `json_lines` file in `output_dir`

    Args:
        json_lines (pathlib.Path): Path to the newline-delimited JSON file to split.
        output_dir (pathlib.Path): Directory where the split JSON files will be saved.
        chunksize (int, optional): Size of each chunk in terms of lines. Defaults to 50,000.

    Returns:
        None
    """

    with json_lines.open("r", encoding="utf-8") as f_in:
        chunked = itertools.islice(f_in, start=0, stop=None, step=chunksize)
        for i, chunk in enumerate(chunked, start=1):
            data = list(map(json.loads, chunk))
            name = pathlib.Path(json_lines).with_suffix("").name
            with (output_dir / f"{name}_{i}.json").open("w", encoding="utf8") as f_out:
                json.dump({"ROOT": data}, f_out, ensure_ascii=False, indent=True)
```

You can then use it as follows (note, I'm moving the archiving logic out of the function):

```py
import shutil

output_dir = pathlib.Path('C:\\Users\\JSON\\Output')
archive_dir = pathlib.Path('C:\\Users\\JSON\\OriginalFiles_BKP')
for file in pathlib.Path("C:\\Users\\JSON\\Input\\").glob("*.json"):
    file_split(file, output_dir)
    shutil.move(file, archive_dir)
```

Note, you should use `pathlib` for path manipulation.